# Java не удается переименовать файл

Tags: java, файлы, файловая-система

У меня есть массив байт, я создаю файл и записываю массив байт в этот файл, потом закрываю запись. Как запись закрыта я хочу переименовать расширение файла.

Мой код:

```
FileOutputStream newFile = new FileOutputStream(rb_Path[0]+"\\"+file_id+".d"); //было .dat

//Записать массив полученных байт в новый файл .dat
newFile.write(byteNewFile);
newFile.flush();

//Закрываем создание нового файла
newFile.close();

File file_d = new File(rb_Path[0]+"\\"+file_id+".d");     
//File file_dat = new File(rb_Path[0]+"\\"+file_id+".dat"); 

//file.d переименовать в file.dat
boolean isRenamed = file_d.renameTo(new java.io.File(rb_Path[0] + "\\" + file_id + ".dat"));
System.out.println(isRenamed);
```

Но получаю false. И как итог не переименовался файл (1234.d на 1234.dat).

Также пробовал так:

```
File file_d = new File(rb_Path[0]+"\\"+file_id+".d");     //Создан 
File file_dat = new File(rb_Path[0]+"\\"+file_id+".dat"); //Не создан, служит объектом для rename

//file.d переименовать в file.dat
boolean isRenamed = file_d.renameTo(file_dat);
System.out.println(isRenamed);
```

Но все равно не получатся изменить расширение с .d на .dat.

- `rb_Path[0]` -  не имеет некорректных символов.
- `file_id` - это int, например 1234

Поэтому даже не знаю как быть.

---

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить такую задачу. Может стоит и вовсе делать все по другому? У кого есть решение? Заранее спасибо большое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы переименовать файл, надо следить за символами в новом и старом имени.

Мой рабочий вариант кода:

```
FileOutputStream newFile = new FileOutputStream(rb_Path[0]+"\\"+file_id+".d"); 

    //Записать массив полученных байт в новый файл .dat
    newFile.write(byteNewFile);
    newFile.flush();
    
    //Закрываем создание нового файла
    newFile.close();
    
    System.out.println(rb_Path[0]); //Выводит: D:/Data/in
    
    File file_d = new File(rb_Path[0]+"\\"+file_id+".d");
    
    //Выводит: D:\Data\in\3406.d
    System.out.println("File.d: "+file_d.getAbsolutePath());
    
    if(file_d.exists()){
    
        String newName = file_d.getAbsolutePath().replace(".d", ".dat");
        
        //Выводит: D:\Data\in\3406.dat
        System.out.println(newName); 

        //file.d переименовать в file.dat
        boolean isRenamed = file_d.renameTo(new File(newName));
        System.out.println(isRenamed);

    }
    else{
    
        System.out.println("Не удалось переименовать файл");
    }
```

---

(Я тестил на WIndows8). Моя ошибка была в непонимании как правильно использовать знаки "/" или "" или вовсе "//". Поэтому если вы сталкиваетесь с подобной ситуацией, помните
и обращайте внимание на это.

Comment: Чтобы не было проблем с разделителями имён в разных платформах,используйте `File.separator`, например так: `rb_Path[0] + File.separator + file_id +".d"`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь буду иметь ввиду.